# Kendo Grid (ASP.NET MVC) - Set column titles of a DataTable-bound grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo grid that is built by using the ASP.NET MVC helpers. The grid is bound to a `DataTable`. If I bind my grid to this `DataTable`, the kendo helper uses the `ColumnName` property of each `DataColumn` to set the title of the column and the field property of the backing object.

The problem is that the column names do and must contain spaces, but if I set a column name to such a value, kendo throws a template error, because the field name cannot contain spaces as that would not be a valid javascript identifier. I tried setting the `Caption` property of the `DataColumn`s but that does not seem to work. The bigger part of the problem is that creating a JS mapper function that would rename each column on the fly (or any workaround using hard-coded values for that matter) is not an option, because my `DataTable` is the result of an SQL pivot operation, so the column names are not at all predictable and therefore no mapping can be done beforehand.

How can I tell Kendo to use different titles for each column from their respective backing fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you iterate the columns in the Grid declaration in the View, you will be able to set custom titles. Check this example and use `column.Title("...");`

https://github.com/telerik/ui-for-aspnet-mvc-examples/blob/master/grid/binding-to-datatable/KendoUIMVC5/Views/Home/Index.cshtml

```
.Columns(columns =>
{
    foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in Model.Columns)
    {
        var c = columns.Bound(column.ColumnName);
        if (column.ColumnName == "UnitPrice")
        {
            c.ClientFooterTemplate("sum:#:sum#").ClientGroupFooterTemplate("sum:#:sum#");
        }
        else if (column.ColumnName == "UnitsInStock")
        {
            c.ClientFooterTemplate("max:#:max#").ClientGroupFooterTemplate("avg:#:average#");
        }
    }
    columns.Command(cmd=>cmd.Edit());
})
```

Comment: Oh, I don't know why I didn't think about that, thanks!